# Passing a parameter to a bash function results in error

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to pass a parameter on the command line to a function defined in ~/.bash_profile. I have looked at a number of solutions on stackoverflow, but they aren't working. Basically, the format is this:

```
function rgrep  { /usr/bin/grep -rl '$@' . | /usr/bin/grep -v 'node_modules' | /usr/bin/grep -v 'bower'; }
```

However, when I try this:

```
rgrep 'foo'
```

I get

```
grep: foo: No such file or directory
```

Comment: `"$@"` instead of single quotes?

Comment: Benjamin W. is correct, but I don't see how you are getting that error message from that code;

Comment: I tried that, too. I tried several permutations.

Comment: I'm on OSX bash, if that helps.

Comment: Wrong `path` to grep ? permissions?

Comment: You probably want to use `"$1"` anyway; `grep` can only take a single pattern argument.

Comment: Tried $1 as well and I have the right path to grep as well as elevated permissions.

Comment: small tip: grep has a little-used `-e` flag, so your filter can be `/usr/bin/grep -F -v -e node_modules -e bower`

Comment: @glennjackman Do you mean `--exclude`?

Comment: Can you add `set -vx;` to the start of `rgrep` and `; set +vx` to the end and then show the output you get from running it?

Comment: I don't see any way you could be getting that error from that function. Do you have an alias that's overriding the function? Try `type rgrep`, and see what that says.

Comment: @EtanReisner, no, `-e` is the `--regexp` option, where you can specific several patterns you want to match without having to combine them into a single regex.

Comment: @glennjackman Ah, you meant to combine the piped calls into `-v -e node_modules -e bower`. I assumed `node_modules` and `bower` there were paths to ignore but maybe not.

Comment: I see. You're right, the `grep -rl ...` call should be using `--exclude` or `--exclude-dir`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, if you get your command sequence to 'work' from the command line then it may work as a 'function' - do the commands 'work' from the command line?

Also, to avoid possible confusion with existing commands, I suggest adding a 'prefix', i.e. 'tf_' # test function.

You need double quotes - (") instead of (')... 
I suggest trying something simpler:

```
function tf_rgrep  { grep -rl "$@" . | grep -ve "node_modules|bower" ;}
```

For debugging add 'set -x':

```
function tf_rgrep  { set -x; grep -rl "$@" . | grep -ve "node_modules|bower" ; set - ;}   

## try 'egrep' if above not working
```

function tf_rgrep  { set -x; egrep -rl "$@" . | egrep -ve "node_modules|bower" ; set - ;}

You save the above to a file, i.e. /tmp/test.functions.sh
Then use 'source' to test...

`source /tmp/test.functions.sh`  # edit and repeat until working

Once ready/working, add to your profile.

:)
Dale

Comment: If I define the function from the command line, it works. If I define it in bash_profile, I get "grep: foo: No such file or directory." This is driving me crazy.

Comment: Did you add the 'set -x' option?  You should get more info on what's going on.  Does it work if you try the 'source ./my_functions.sh'?

Comment: Actually, prefixing the function name fixed it. Weird as rgrep is not in the path and not a command that I know of. `set -x` didn't really help.

Comment: To locate any command in your path you might try: 'which Some_Command' OR perhaps something like: 'for F in ${PATH//:/ } ; do ls -ld ${F}/grep 2> /dev/null ; done'; you might also try 'typeset -F' and 'typeset -f'... :)